# UIcollectionView Custom Shape Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uicollectionview

I have a UIView then I put small UIImageViews with an image but I would like to replace this with a UICollectionView. I am not sure how to make the cells go in a upside down U shape like this. [image: UIImageViews in UIView]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: u cannot do it wth one colelctionview. YOu should add collectionview to tableView cell!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri So I could do this with a UITableView? Can you please explain?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Actually this is what UICollectionView is for, however, this is an **advanced** subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout and really not something to "ask" for a solution here on SO, however, Google and you will find some tutorials regarding custom layouts, for example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what UICollectionView is for, however, this is an **advanced** subclass of [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout) 
 and really not something to "ask" for a solution here on SO, however, Google and you will find some tutorials regarding custom layouts, [for example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel).

If you have no dynamic updates or movement of the `UIImageViews`, and they will **always** be visible on the UI (not move out of the screen) you really don't need a `UICollectionView` for this, but rather a customized `UIView` with your custom `UIImageViews` on it.

You could do this in a `XIB` subclassed `UIView` and with `AutoLayout` for example. (You can still customize it to dynamically update and move of course if needed)

Sidenote:

If the `UIImages` loaded into the `UIImageViews` are big sized, they will soak your memory and you will probably run into memory problems, make sure your `UIImage` are **thumbnails** and according to the **displayed UIView size**.